# What are the diagonal and off-diagonal elements of the stress tensor?

Tags: fluid-dynamics, stress-energy-momentum-tensor, stress-strain

what does a typical diagonal element $\sigma_{xx}$ and off-diagonal element $\sigma_{xy}$ of the second rank [stress tensor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy_stress_tensor) $\sigma_{ij}$ physically signify?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you lay a book on a table and press down on it, you are applying a unidirectional stress, like ${{\sigma }_{xx}}$, if *x* denotes the vertical direction.  Pressure is defined as the average of the three diagonal stress values.  On the other hand, if you shove its cover horizontally, you are applying a shear stress, like ${{\sigma }_{xy}}$.

Comment: What is the origin of this shear stress in solids and liquids?

Comment: @mithusengupta123, that's a completely different question.

Comment: Origin?  Almost always an external force being applied somewhere to compress or deform the material, although not at the same point where you are measuring stress.  In liquids, there will also be viscous stress proportional to shear rate.  In solids, stress will be proportional to strain.

Answer (score 0):

$\sigma_{xx}$ represents the stress on a plane of constant x in the x direction.  $\sigma_{xy}$ represents the stress on a plane of constant x in the y direction; and, because the stress tensor is symmetric, it is also equal to the stress on a plane of constant y in the x direction.

In a solid, the shear stress is proportional to the amount of shear strain between parallel adjacent planes; in a liquid, the shear stress is proportional to the rate of shear strain between parallel adjacent planes.

Comment: Why do you say that the stress tensor is symmetric? Is it always true?

Comment: It follows from the fact that the behavior of a solid or liquid must be independent of  any arbitrary rotation of the observer.